# PHP and MySQL - efficiently handling multiple one to many relationships

Tags: php, mysql, one-to-many

I am seeking some advice on the best way to retrieve and display my data using MySQL and PHP.

I have 3 tables, all 1 to many relationships as follows:

Each **SCHEDULE** has many **OVERRIDES** and each override has many **LOCATIONS**. I would like to retrieve this data so that it can all be displayed on a single PHP page e.g. list out my SCHEDULES. Within each schedule list the OVERRIDES, and within each override list the LOCATIONS.

**Option1** - Is the best way to do this make 3 separate SQL queries and then write these to a PHP object? I could then iterate through each array and check for a match on the parent array.

**Option 2** - I have thought quite a bit about joins however doing two right joins will return me a row for every entrance in all 3 tables.

Any thoughts and comments would be appreciated.

Best regards, Ben.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you really want every piece of data, you're going to be retrieving the same number of rows, no matter how you do it.  Best to get it all in one query.

```
SELECT schedule.id, overrides.id, locations.id, locations.name
FROM schedule
JOIN overrides ON overrides.schedule_id = schedule.id
JOIN locations ON locations.override_id = overrides.id
ORDER BY schedule.id, overrides.id, locations.id
```

By ordering the results like this, you can iterate through the result set and move on to the next schedule whenever the scheduleid changes, and the next location when the locationid changes.

Edit: a possible example of how to turn this data into a 3-dimensional array -

```
$last_schedule = 0;
$last_override = 0;
$schedules = array();

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query_result))
{
  $schedule_id = $row[0];
  $override_id = $row[1];
  $location_id = $row[2];
  $location_name = $row[3];
  if ($schedule_id != $last_schedule)
  {
    $schedules[$schedule_id] = array();
  }
  if ($override_id != $last_override)
  {
    $schedules[$schedule_id][$override_id] = array();
  }
  $schedules[$schedule_id][$override_id][$location_id] = $location_name;
  $last_schedule = $schedule_id;
  $last_override = $override_id;
}
```

Quite primitive, I imagine your code will look different, but hopefully it makes some sense.

Comment: yes good point, the same number of rows will be returned either way. Regarding display, I just need to display each schedule as a section of the page, and within each schedule I need to list each Override with its locations. Should be fine running through an array.

I am interested in your comment around moving on to the next schedule when the schedule id changes. Can you advise?

Many thanks in advance, I shall proceed with the single DB query.

Best regards, Ben.

Comment: I added a code sample which will hopefully point you in a useful direction.