# One to many relationship in MySQL, Selecting "child" table information

Tags: php, mysql, json, hierarchical-data

I have written some PHP scripts to make pulling information out of a series of MySQL tables easier, however there are severe performance problems.  As a result I'm trying to reduce the number of queries.

The tables have a one to many relationship:
Parent Table (parent_id, first, last, phone)
Child Table (child_id, parent_id, date, request, details)

So, for any entry in the parent table there may be multiple associated rows in the child table.  How, can I select a row in the parent table and use the parent_id (primary key) to pull all the associated rows from the child table?

```
SELECT * FROM `Parent Table` WHERE `parent_id` = 5
```

...and then...

```
SELECT * FROM `Child Table` WHERE `parent_id` = '5'
```

I want to then take the result and put it into an associative array, and json_encode to return as JSON.

To clarify, I already have this working, but it's doing an additional query for each row selected, so instead of one query it is doing 101 for 100 rows.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:** It has been suggested to use Joins, however a new problem arises

Sample data:
Parent table (1, 'albert', 'smith', '12345')
Child table (1, 1, 2010-10-5, 'test', 'etc etc'), (2, 1, 2010-10-6, 'again', 'eg eg')

Doing a join results in two rows

> 1, albert, smith, 12345, 1, 1, 2010-10-5, test, etc etc
>
> 1, albert, smith, 12345, 2, 1, 2010-10-6, again, eg eg

So, I have two rows with the parent table information duplicated.  To use joins I need some way of cleaning this up, and putting it into a hierarchical form.

The result should be 
    `{parent_id:1, first:albert, last:smith, phone:12345, child_table:[{child_id:1,        date:2010-10-5, request:test, details:'etc etc'},{child_id:2, date:2010-10-6,   request:again, details:'eg eg'}]}`

**SOLUTION:** So, the answer for me is to use joins, and write a function to convert the returned rows into an associative array

**mysqlResult** is an associative array from a mysql_query call, 
**parent_key** is the name of the primary key of the parent table,
**child_key** is the name of the primary key of the child table,
**child_table** is the name of the child table,
**child_fields** is an associative array of the names of all the fields in the child table

```
   function cleanJoin($mysqlResult, $parent_key, $child_key, $child_table, $child_fields)
    {
    $last_parent = 0;
    $last_child = 0;
    $ch_ctr = 0;

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($mysqlResult); $i++)
    {
        if ($mysqlResult[$i][$child_key] != $last_child)
        {
            echo "new child!";
            $pr_ctr = count($answer[$i]);
            foreach ($child_fields as $field => $type)
            {
               $answer[$pr_ctr][$child_table][$ch_ctr][$field] = $mysqlResult[$i][$field];
               unset($mysqlResult[$field]);
            }
            $ch_ctr++;
        }
        if ($mysqlResult[$i][$parent_key] != $last_parent)
        {
            foreach($mysqlResult[$i] as $field => $value)
            {
                $answer[$i][$field] = $value;
            }
        }
        $last_parent = $mysqlResult[$i][$parent_key];
        $last_child = $mysqlResult[$i][$child_key];
    }

    return $answer;
}
```

Comment: If you cannot switch to the nested set model, you are more or less out of luck due to MySQL lacking support for recursive queries.

Comment: I'm just not sure how I can transition.  Perhaps a better example is having a post, and then a series of comments to that post.  The comments are stored in a separate table, but have the post_id to link to it.  How could I then pull the post and all the comments?  Alternatively, how could I have this in a nested set model?

Comment: Your tables show no hierarchy structure, just a one-to-many relationship between posts and commenst. Do you really need comments on comments? And comments on comments to comments?

Comment: It's just an example, comments to a post are still one level of hierarchy.  Even then, it sounds like there's no way to do that?

Comment: Yes, but you should use an hierarchical structure when you need many (or infinite) levels.

Comment: Currently I have 2 levels of hierarchy.  A client, then a client's admissions, then tests conducted during admission.

Comment: I've changed the subject to one to many relationship rather than hierarchical.

Comment: Credit to this answer which helped me write this function http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4820742/php-and-mysql-efficiently-handling-multiple-one-to-many-relationships/4820812#4820812

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe i am reading the question wrong, but have you looked at joins?

```
SELECT * FROM `Parent Table` 
join `Child Table` ON `Child Table`.`Parent ID`=`Parent Table`.`ID`
WHERE `parent_id` = 5
```

example of assoc array of consilidated data

```
 $res = mysql_query($sql);

 $output = array();

 while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {

    $parent_name = $row['parent_name'];  
    $child_name = $row['child_name'];

    $output[$parent_name][] = $child_name; 
}

var_dump($output);
```

Comment: It's a good solution, the problem I have is for each child row it returns a row.  So, you end up with say 5 rows when really I want one row, with 5 child rows nested inside of it(so I can return JSON).  I think I'm going to have to find a way of taking the many rows and consolidating it into an associative array in PHP

Comment: amended answer to show how to build that assoc array sturcture from query

Comment: The problem with joins is that it just mashes all the variables together, and adds as many rows as there are in the child table, with duplicate information from the parent table.  I've edited the original post to explain the problem with joins, and why I still need someway to clean up the data

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest caching your JSON in a PHP file and update it only when something is changed

Such cases unfortunately are heavy to the DB and I personally don't know any way to do it...