# comma separated value into array

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am creating a database for students.

I created a table "Subjects"

```
ID    NAME
1     Maths
2     Science
3     Biology
4     Social Studies
```

I created another table "Students"

```
ID    Name         Subject
1     Ram          1,2,3
2     Shyam        1,3,4
3     Hanuman      1,2,3,4
```

I want to retrieve the name of students into a php page and also show their subjects, how do I do this :

```
Name          Subject
Ram           Maths, Science, Biology
Shyam         Maths, Biology, Social Studies
```

etc.

I am new to PHP, MySQL.

Comment: your db schema is wrong,you should not  have a comma separated list in a single field. you should have a sudent-subject table, with student id and subject id

Comment: This is a one-to-many relationship ([http://stackoverflow.com/q/7799675/2493918](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7799675/2493918)).

Answer (score 4):

1. The starting point is to remove subject from the students tables
2. and create a "[pivot-table](https://www.google.com/search?q=mysql%20pivot%20table)" called *student-subject*

**For example:**

```
+------------+------------+
| student_id | subject_id |
+------------+------------+
| 1          | 1          |
| 1          | 2          |
| 1          | 3          |
| 2          | 1          |
+------------+------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Like other pointed out, your schema is really not optimal but you can achieve what you want to do with this query :

```
select st.Name, group_concat(su.name ORDER BY su.ID)
from Students st
inner join Subjects su on concat(',',st.Subject,',') like concat('%,',su.ID,',%')
group by st.Name
```

See SQLFIDDLE : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/79286d/8/0

Answer (score 1):

**The following code works with the database stucture you have now, below a better solution**
The fastest way in php is to select information as few times as possible. You can join the tables, but joins are slow, so we try other methods. You could select the name of the subject for each course, which will be less heavy on the database per query, but you are making allot of small queries, so you dont prefer that aswell.

My suggested method selects all the subjects and store them in an array. By settings the key the same as the id of the subject, you can access the information further along via that key, which is very fast.

```
// Select all subjects:
$qSubj = "SELECT id,name FROM Subjects"; 
$sSubj = mysql_query($qSubj) or die(mysql_error()); // note: die() isnt pretty, and mysql_ should be mysqli_
// Set the variable which is going to store our information:
$subjects = array();
// For each row found, add a line:
while($fSubj = mysql_fetch_assoc($sSubj)){
    $subjects[ $fSubj['id'] ] = $fSubj; // here we save it, $subjects[2] will have the information of 'Science'
}

// Now we have the subjects, we can continue to the larger table:
$qStudent = "SELECT id,name,subjects FROM Students";
$sStudent = mysql_query($qStudent ) or die(mysql_error()); // note: die() isnt pretty, and mysql_ should be mysqli_
// Now we have selected the users, loop through them:
while($fStudent = mysql_fetch_assoc($sStudent )){
    // Here you can do whatever you want :) Im not a fan of echoing in this stage of the code
    // I prefer storing everything in something like $template, and output it at the end
    echo $fStudent['name'].' has following subjects: ';
    $courses = explode(",", $fStudent['subjects']); // By exploding on the comma, youhave them seperatly:
    foreach($courses as $k =>$subject_id){ // for each subject, get the name
        echo $subjects[ $subject_id ]['name'].' '; // Here we can use the information we stored earlier
    }
}
```

**The better solution:**
You now have a foreach() in the while() that fetches the users. If yuou have a few lines, this is no big deal, but if you have 100+ lines to display, this foreach-loop will make it slower. The better method is to add another table, linking the both of them:

Subject: id, name
Students: id, name
student_subject: student_id, subject_id.

The last table does about the same as your student.subjects column, but this is in the database instead in an array in php. PHP and loops aren't the best friends, you should add the connection in the student_subject's table and replace the foreach() in the student's while() with a query to select all the subject_id's for that student.

Comment: this is a LOT slower that a the proper schema and the use of JOINS

Comment: I'd like to see some examples if you can. To my experience, this is WAY faster than joins. And I work with medium-large datasets, so any performance would be noticable

Comment: With this current table setup, this is the fastest way to my experience. I agree with you on the part that this has to be normalized and add another table to connect the both, so the foreach() in the students while() does not have to work. I Dont like loops in PHP like this

Comment: well the point is the current set up is wrong, doesn't it make more sense to change that (by normalisation)? then hack around it.

Comment: Yes, but I provided an anwser for the current problem :) I remember when I started everybody gave me solutions which I didnt understand, I prefered a working solution, and then a solution which would be more proper

Comment: that's the classic X-Y problem though, you are just going to make it harder on the OP down the track

Answer (score -2):

You could also retrieve the subjects column, explode the results into an array, then lookup each subject's name through a foreach statement.

```
$subjects = array(1,2,3);

foreach ($subjects as $subject){
    $result = $db->query("SELECT `name` FROM `Subjects` WHERE `ID` = $subject");
         while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo $row['name'];
    }
}
```